# Is it possible to access custom tabs in 1:1 chats in MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am looking for a way to add a custom tab to 1:1 conversations in MS Teams. The documentation is a little contradicting on this topic:

> Currently, you can add one or more static tabs to your app's **"personal scope"** experience, accessed via the app bar or alongside your app's bot conversation.
>
> From [Create a static tab in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-static)

and

> Microsoft Teams supports tabs in either:
>
> - Teams - (channel) ...
> - **Personal - (1:1 conversations or chats)** ...
>
> From [Teams scopes for tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview#teams-scopes-for-tabs)

I have tried building a custom tab and looking for a way to access it in a chat, but to no success.

I would like to clarify: is the following correct?

- Static tabs can **only** be accessed via the app bar or in conversation with my app's bot
- Static tabs **cannot** be accessed in 1:1 or group chats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static tabs can only be accessed via the app bar or in conversation with your app's bot. Currently Static tabs are not accessible in 1:1/group conversation with other users. As of now Bot can not be added in group conversation.